# How to create treeview for multiple columns in sharepoint List with Context Menu of List Items?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, development

I created a SharePoint custom list with columns.(Column name col1 ,col2 ,col3 col4, col5)

I want to create a view with this columns to display the data as like Treeview structure.

Using groupby only two columns is possible to disply in treeview.
I want to configure 5 columns.

[image]

To achieve this how can i set the column data types

Col1 is single line of text. if I add any value in col2 it will come under Col1.
so for Col2 I have to create lookup or any other data type.

If i add other country to col1 it will not come under by India.

Each list items contains Context Menu add,delete,Edit..ect

without using Sharepoint Designer its possible to achieve this scenario using C#.
Can anyone help me on that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you better to use **Manage Metadata** Data type (Taxonomy Content Type) to achieve this else need to go for customisation.

Comment: I edited my question and I added one image I want that exact view in SharePoint custom  list

Comment: Using Groupby it possible to add only 2 columns is there any way to map more than 2 columns using groupby ?